# How to change Class object name in a loop

Tags: class, python-3.x, object

So I have Class

```
class MyClass
....do things...
```

and I add objects to it with

```
ObjName = MyClass(things)
```

and my problem is that when I add ObjName to MyClass in a loop, I can't figure out a way to create a new object name each loop so it keeps overwriting the only Obj this ends up creating. I tried adding a list as in

```
ObjName[i] = MyClass(things)
```

but it wouldn't work.

Here is what I'm trying to do specifically (edited for clarity):

So when I add objects to MyClass, the name of the object added should be callable with input, like so:

```
somename = input("objname: ")  # User input decides how the object values can be called
TempObjName = MyClass(things) # Values of the specific object, will contain more than one unique object
*...*
somename.someattribute() ## 2 different
somename2.someattribute() ## values, sets or etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ObjList = []
for i in whatever:
     temp = MyClass(things)
     ObjList.extend(temp)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm able to use this, but from what I could gather it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I think I was a bit unclear in my initial post, so sorry about that.

This method here only added the string to the list of strings and each string was made into one character long. I'm not sure if I could use this in some warped way, but anyways, I edited my original post to better communicate what I tried/try to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to create the function I wanted per-say, but because my code had a dictionary that saved the obj name and obj value in it, I was able to do what I initially wanted to do by rerunning the requested name from the dictionary in the Class.